# Member function template to call a funcion on a data member with arbitrary arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I'm working on a C++11 code base and wondering how I can call any function on a member type passing arbitrary arguments. **Note that since I'm using C++11 I can't use something like `std::invoke`**.

I started creating a function template in the `Outer` class, but my initial try gives me a compile error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct Inner {
  void bar(int x) {
    std::cout << "Called: x=" << x << std::endl;
  }
};

struct Outer {
  explicit Outer(Inner *i) : b{i} {}
  void foo(int) {}
  Inner* b;

  template <typename Func, typename ... Args>
  void CallInner(Func&& f, Args&& ... args) {
    b->f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};


int main() {
  Inner inner{};
  Outer outer(&inner);
  outer.CallInner(&Inner::bar, 5);
}
```

[Try it out yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/BarpyA)

Again, I would like to keep the signature of the function `CallInner` unchanged from the above sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `f` is a pointer a member function it needs to be dereferenced first before being called:

```
(b->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have much choice with regards to changing the signature, because at least one additional template is required.

The correct syntax is a little bit more complicated:

```
struct Outer {
  explicit Outer(Inner *i) : b{i} {}
  void foo(int) {}
  Inner* b;

    template <typename Ret, typename ...FuncArgs,  typename ... Args>
    void CallInner(Ret (Inner::*f)(FuncArgs...), Args&& ... args) {
        (b->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

The first parameter to `CallInner` must be a method pointer, and, in a template context, it needs to be templated not just by a set of variadic template parameters, `FuncArgs`, but also its return type, `Ret`. Then you also need a second set of variadic template parameters for the forwarding references of the arguments you're forwarding (which may not necessarily be the same as `FuncArgs`, hence the need for a separate set of variadic template types).